Nextjs/Typescript - recreation of scroll, image/text animation, fadeins
I am trying to recreate a demo template https://az-bold.webflow.io/ that uses scroll effects and mouse location tracking in nextjs/typescript.
I saw there was a horizontal scroll problem that does get fixed with an overflow:hidden on the section tags -- but then this breaks any sticky content interactions..
I've not seen any examples of how to properly recreate these actions - and I am unsure how to manipulate the styles/dom to recreate the effect correctly.
I've started creating a function that can manipulate these elements - but how to bind it and animate it correctly against mouse events
on load there is title animation where the text is large, then shrinks, then resumes into its current place

On the sides the rings are rotating


// Hero Section
const Hero = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    var ellipseLeft = document.querySelector(".ellipse-left");
    var ellipseRight = document.querySelector(".ellipse-right");
    //document.querySelectorAll('[data-fill]').forEach(elem => {
    //  elem.style.width = elem.getAttribute("data-fill");
    //});

    var rotateZ = 23;

    setInterval(() => {
      rotateZ++;
      console.log("this is the first message");

      ellipseRight.style.transform =
        "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(" +
        rotateZ +
        "deg) skew(0deg, 0deg)";
      ellipseRight.style["transform-style"] = "preserve-3d";
      ellipseRight.style["will-change"] = "transform";

      ellipseLeft.style.transform =
        "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(" +
        rotateZ +
        "deg) skew(0deg, 0deg)";
      ellipseLeft.style["transform-style"] = "preserve-3d";
      ellipseLeft.style["will-change"] = "transform";
    }, 50);
  }, []);

on scroll the phone unlocks and the text parallax

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fervent-fast-forked-wcsmh4
https://wcsmh4.csb.app/
on reveal for the first time - these parts fade in smoothly

there is a contrast transition from light to dark in this section based on the direction and speed of scroll


To recreate the scroll effects, image/text animation, and fade-ins in a Next.js project with TypeScript, you can utilize libraries such as framer-motion for animations and react-intersection-observer for handling scroll-based animations.
Below is a basic example demonstrating how to structure your components to achieve similar effects:
jsx
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { motion, useAnimation } from 'framer-motion';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';

const HeroSection = () => {
    const controls = useAnimation();
    const [ref, inView] = useInView();
    const titleRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inView) {
            controls.start('visible');
        }
    }, [controls, inView]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (titleRef.current) {
            const titleTimeline = controls
                .sequence()
                .add({ scale: 1.2, transition: { duration: 0.5 } })
                .add({ scale: 1, transition: { duration: 0.5 } });

            titleTimeline.start();
        }
    }, [controls]);

    return (
        <section className="hero" ref={ref}>
            <motion.div
                className="title"
                ref={titleRef}
                initial={{ scale: 0 }}
                animate={controls}
            >
                Your Title Here
            </motion.div>
            {/* Other content and animations */}
        </section>
    );
};

export default HeroSection;

Explanation:
We use react-intersection-observer to detect when the component comes into view.
When the component is in view, we start the animation sequence defined by framer-motion controls.
For the title animation, we use a useRef hook to get a reference to the title element and animate it when it comes into view.
You can add other animations and effects similarly using framer-motion controls and hooks.
Make sure to install framer-motion and react-intersection-observer:
bash
npm install framer-motion
npm install react-intersection-observer

Remember to import these dependencies at the top of your file as well:
jsx
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { motion, useAnimation } from 'framer-motion';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';

This code provides a basic structure for implementing scroll-based animations and fade-ins in a Next.js TypeScript project. You can expand upon this by adding more animations and interactions as needed.

This seems to be an AI answer.

you have a sandbox showcasing this -- also does this answer all the other animation parts to the different sections?

framer-motion, react-intersection-observer -- cant this be handled without adding more modules?
